# Как обнаружить скрипт, который запускает открытие календаря

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

На странице создания задачи, дата выбирается в календаре, который вызывается посредством щелчка на значке календаря с права от поля даты. Мне нужно найти скрипт, который срабатывает при щелчке на значек календаря чтобы понять как он работает, как он обрабатывает сам клик и на каком точно элементе установлен обработчик события.

Comment: Восользуйтесь инструментами разработчика в любом бразуере.

Answer (score 1):

Для вывода поля даты (вместе с иконкой календаря) используется компонент bitrix:main.calendar.
В шаблоне компонента подключается calendar.js.
Создав свой шаблон, к примеру используя поддержку [/local/](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=5119), вы можете его кастомизировать под свои задачи.

Comment: А не могли бы вы уточнить: в каком файле происходит установка обработчика события клика? Я хочу понять, каким образом определяется, что пользователь кликнул на иконку календаря, а не просто на любой участок textbox в который вводиться дата.

Comment: В шаблоне компонента файл template.php 
onclick="BX.calendar....

[мануал по onclick](http://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events)  ,
[документация по BX.calendar](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/js_lib/data/calendar.php)

Comment: К сожалению, там не все так просто. В моих изысканиях, мне удалось обнаружить набор js файлов соответствующих шаблону задач:  "bitrix\js\tasks" и в файле"datepicker.js" код:     this.bindDelegateControl('display', 'click', this.passCtx(this.onInputClicked));    устанавливающий обработчик события, но в этом обработчике всего лишь открывается само окно выбора даты, а где-то  в недрах битрикс скрыт способ отслеживания события и выбор того при клике на какой именно участок элемента оно должно срабатывать.

Comment: Вы уже уходите в ядро системы. Зачем? Переформулируйте вашу задачу.
onclick на иконку вызывает ф-ию BX.calendar, которая рисует календарь.
Что бы понять как работает календарь, вам и нужно изучать ее код.
Это исчерпывающий ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: В своем вопросе, я просил помочь Мне разобраться с тем, как он работает, как он обрабатывает сам клик и на каком точно элементе установлен
обработчик события. Меня не интересует работа с календарем, мне нужно только понять как обрабатывается само событие, каким образом обработчик решает, что пользователь кликнул именно по иконке календаря, а не просто на поля выбора даты. Я даже был бы рад, если бы мне просто абстрактно описали каким образом это реализуется, но конечно идеально увидеть как это делается в самом Битрикс.

Comment: Я понимаю, что отслеживается onclick, я вижу, что они устанавливают обработчик события на определенное поле, и что отображают по клику окно выбора даты, но мне не удается обнаружить код, который определяет , что пользователь кликнул именно по иконке календаря. Прошу прощение, если не достаточно точно изначально сформулировал вопрос.

Comment: Вы не понимаете принцип работы атрибуты onclick. Начните с основ http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onclick

Comment: Конечно понимаю, и конечно там не используется атрибут onclick. Это очевидно любому кто посмотрит на разметку страницы к которой относится вопрос, а если учесть, что работает это похожим образом во всей системе...